# Elasticsearch won't start on centos, permission denied

Tags: elasticsearch, permissions, centos, permission-denied

I installed elasticsearch this way :
retrieved the tar.gz on windows, extracted it and put it on a zip
uploaded the zip over ssh on a server and use 'unzip file' to unzip it.

I modified the elasticsearch file so that it has this line

```
export JAVA_HOME = "/home/xxx/project1/jdk1.8.0_73_linux64"
```

just below

```
#!/bin/sh
```

now when I go into /home/xxx/project1/elasticsearch/bin and type

```
./elasticsearch
```

I get

```
-bash: ./elasticsearch: Permission denied
```

What could I do to get more information about the problem?
I'm logged as user xxx

Thanks.

Comment: you may have provide the write permission, the elasticsearch will have default logging functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install using the package [Yum Install for elasticsearch.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html#_yum_dnf)

**Else try:** Its sounds like the user permission to access the files.

- Ensure that you have downloaded the linux distribution (Optional) Since you have mentioned its tar.gz.
- If you have extracted using `sudo` command then you need to change the user permission for elasticsearch folder to logged in user OR start the `elasticsearch` using `sudo` command

> sudo ./elasticsearch -d

- Check the execution permission if not please do the same by following command

> sudo chmod +x /home/xxx/project1/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch.sh

Try this things if not please create a chat window and invite me.

Comment: nope I extracted it with the 'ath' user which is not in the sudo list. (into the /home/ath folder)

Comment: check for the execution mode.

Comment: Well turn out if you type 'bash elasticsearch' it start otherwhise you have to do chmod +x.

Coul you explain why? I mean each time I extract a software on a linux I have to chmod +x every executable files? (I had to also to it for the file the script was calling)

Comment: http://www.linuxnix.com/chmod-command-explained-linuxunix/ This will help you to understand the `chmod` command

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that you've installed elastic being logged in as root. Now you're surely logged in as not root. If you're working as a user with root privileges, you potentially could start elastic, but it tells you, you can't run in as root. The owner of your elastic folder is root (he installed it). So, all you need to do is to change the owner of a folder to your xxx-user (to let him run elastic). You can easily do it executing a command:

```
chown -R new_owner path
```

for example, user is xxx and path is /opt/elasticsearch-2.3.5:

```
chown -R xxx /opt/elasticsearch-2.3.5
```

"-R" parameter ensures, that not only folder, but all files inside will recursively change the owner you provide.

Answer (score 2):

Looking ahead I will immediately say that the ES app **doesn't work** using the `sudo`

In my case with *ES 6.8.1* version on *ubuntu* i solved the problem using this steps:

1. Add the current user(or any other) to ES group:

   `sudo adduser <yourName> elasticsearch`
2. Add possibility to execute ES:

   `sudo chmod +x /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`
3. Then i changed owner of some paths**, in my case these were:

   `sudo chown -R <yourName>:elasticsearch /etc/default/elasticsearch`

   `sudo chown -R <yourName>:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch`

   `sudo chown -R <yourName>:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch`

**I started the application several times and then looked where I had no permission

Then i started ./usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch and saw the long-awaited JSON on port 9200 :)

Hope this will help someone.